# Selecting timestamp records in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, timezone, timestamp

How do I select records in Postgres that have hour values greater than 00:00:00? The field type is Timestamp with time zone.

Example record:

"2012-07-30 07:00:00-07"

I need everything that is greater than 00:00:00

Comment: What did you try before posting? Did you search? Also, what's your PostgreSQL version? I'd usually downvote this as a low-effort question, but you *did* include sample data and expected results, and you're new. A search like [`[postgresql] timestamp hour`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostgresql%5D+timestamp+hour) would've found helpful answers, as would https://www.google.com/search?q=postgresql+timestamp+hour+greater+than

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `extract(hour from ...)`. See the [PostgreSQL date/time functions in the user manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html).

```
CREATE TABLE test AS SELECT TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2012-07-30 07:00:00-07' AS tstamp;

SELECT tstamp FROM test WHERE extract(hour from tstamp) > 0;
```

Comment: Maybe `(tstamp - date_trunc('day', tstamp) > interval '1 second')` ?

`extract(hour from tstamp)` wont help with "2012-07-30 00:59:59-07" .

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko It's not clear whether the poster means "have a time value greater than zero" or "have an hours value greater than zero". The 1st statement implies hours, the second implies time. For "Anything greater than 00:00:00" you're right; for "hour values greater than zero" my answer is. Poorly framed question.

Comment: @Cen Note Igor's comment for an important difference. Did you really mean "hours greater than zero" or did you mean "*time* greater than zero"?